# Why is Orca's "Import Text File" option grayed out?

Tags: import, windows-installer, orca

I'm trying to import a text file into an MSI cell, but Orca's option to do so is disabled.

[image]

My file isn't read only or in use.  How can I enable that option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only unbounded string columns (`String[0]`) are compatible with the Insert Text File option.  Other column types - even `String[255]` - don't accept (and won't truncate) arbitrary-length text.